# Single word for "hospital woman worker"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I have been looking for a single word for "hospital woman worker". She will not do any medical related work. She will be doing cleaning, newborn care, and she will also support all the work of hospital employees. Can anyone tell me the single word for "hospital woman worker"?

Comment: British English certainly doesn't have sex-differentiated words for this type of thing (*nurse* is effectively unisex, and *matron* is passe, for example). Regardless of gender, such people are likely to be called [**nursing auxiliaries** or **healthcare assistants**](http://www.nhscareers.nhs.uk/explore-by-career/wider-healthcare-team/careers-in-the-wider-healthcare-team/clinical-support-staff/healthcare-assistant/).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Candy striper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospital_volunteer) - A hospital volunteer is sometimes nicknamed a candy striper. This name is derived from the red-and-white striped jumpers that female volunteers traditionally wore in the United States, which resembled stick candy.

I know its not a "single word" but when I read your question Candy Striper came immediately to mind.  There are also various levels of nursing, but the term [nurse](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nurse) does not indicate gender, and often concerns many medical functions in the hospital.  Candy stripers are not permitted for perform medical functions, as they are volunteers rather than employees of the hospital.

Comment: I have a doubt. Can i have gender as woman for "Candy Striper"?.

Comment: I believe that the term is gender neutral, but the origin is specifically feminine.

Comment: This is a very regional term and only applicable in the United States of America.

Answer (score 3):

Hospitals, like most work environments, are tending more away from traditional roles that were dependent upon or at least customarily assigned to members of a specific gender, like nursing or maintenance workers. There are very few gender dependent roles in healthcare or in any business any more, so "hospital woman worker" is likely not an accurate descriptor for any hospital role.

*Candy striper* is a passé description of young, typically teen, volunteers and that terminology is not generally in use any longer.  Most organizations call non-nursing unlicensed workers in clinical settings "[nurse technicians](http://education-portal.com/what_is_a_nurse_technician.html)," "nurse techs" or just "techs," implying that they require some specific training for their jobs but not formal training that results in licensure.

Comment: Do you say "Candy striper" not relevant word for "Hospital Woman Worker".?. If not please provide exact word for this term.

Comment: I added a link because it provides a job description.